# Include collection in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

For example, I have those entities:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public List<BookPage> Pages { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
} 

public class BookPage
{
    [Key]
    public string BookPageId { get; set; }
    public PageTitle PageTitle { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class PageTitle
{
    [Key]
    public string PageTitleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

How should I load all PageTitles, if I know only the BookId?

Here it is how I'm trying to do this:

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext
        .Book
        .Include(x => x.Pages)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Select(y => y.PageTitle))
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
        .Pages
        .Select(x => x.PageTitle)
        .ToList();
}
```

But the problem is, that it throws exception

> ArgumentException: The properties expression 'x => {from Pages y
>   in x select [y].PageTitle}' is not valid. The expression should represent
>   a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple
>   properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1,
>   t.MyProperty2 }'. Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

What's wrong, what exactly should I do?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try accessing `PageTitle` directly in `ThenInclude`:

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext
    .Book
    .Include(x => x.Pages)
    .ThenInclude(y => y.PageTitle)
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
    .Select(x => x.Pages)
    .Select(x => x.PageTitle)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: how it is works? I mean, when I'm typing y.PageTitle, I don't have Intellisense field with PageTitle, but it works, builds!

Comment: @YuriyN. It's because you use this overload: `ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>([NotNullAttribute] this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)`. VS intellisense sees the other one which is `ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>([NotNullAttribute] this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ` **IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>** `> source, [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)`