# Can't include objects of nested list with Entity query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and I have the following structure:

```
class Foo
{
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public XPTO Xpto { get; set; }
}

class XPTO
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

How can I include in my Linq query the XPTO Object?

I have tried:

```
context.Foo.Include(o => o.Bars).ToList(); // This gets me the Bars but the XPTO's of them are null

context.Foo.Include(o => o.Bars).ThenInclude(o => o.Select(x => x.Xpto)).ToList(); This throws an error:
```

> System.ArgumentException: The property expression 'o => {from Bar in o
>   select [x].Xpto}' is not valid. The expression should represent a
>   property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601380/5621827 this may help

Comment: It doesnt. In my `ThenInclude` I only have access to the `Collection` properties. I tried using that `Select` to get the field I want but it is throwing error

Comment: What's the error you receive when you write ThenInclude(o => o.Xpto) ?because if you see the comment on above post you will not get any  Intellisense help for that but it would still works

Comment: *facepalm* 
Yes man, that worked. I thought because mine was a collection it would be different. Sorry. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Nope glad it help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for someone else facing the same problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601380/5621827)

```
 context.Foo.Include(o => o.Bars).ThenInclude(x => x.Xpto).ToList();
```

you may not get any  Intellisense help for that but it would still work with ef core.